# Shuffling rows in Pandas DataFrame every 14 rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame of size `(1064, 10)` and I wanted to shuffle the rows every 14 rows, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import sklearn
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/melangev2.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame({})

for i in list(range(76)):  # i \in {0,1,2,...,75}
  df.append(dataset.iloc[14*i: 14*(i+1)].sample(frac = 1))
  i += 1

print(df)
```

But it outputs an empty list, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cols = df.columns
df = df.groupby(df.index//14)[cols].apply(lambda x:x.sample(frac=1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Conside a sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col_1':np.arange(1,16), 'col_2': np.arange(21, 36)})
```

Input:

```
    col_1  col_2
0       1     21
1       2     22
2       3     23
3       4     24
4       5     25
5       6     26
6       7     27
7       8     28
8       9     29
9      10     30
10     11     31
11     12     32
12     13     33
13     14     34
14     15     35
```

Resampling it every 5 rows:

```
cols = df.columns
df = df.groupby(df.index//5)[cols].apply(lambda x:x.sample(frac=1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     col_1  col_2
0       2     22
1       1     21
2       5     25
3       3     23
4       4     24
5       8     28
6       6     26
7       7     27
8       9     29
9      10     30
10     14     34
11     13     33
12     11     31
13     15     35
14     12     32
```